# How to have ONLY one symbol from a certain package without it affecting the rest of the document

Tags: symbols, packages

{Disclaimer: I am a noob at LaTeX and coding}

I want to use a symbol from the package "oz". It is the `$\fcmp$` symbol.

When I have \usepackage{oz} in my document however, it changes almost every symbol. This is a problem because it defaults to italic letters in math mode and I am using italic letters for something else. It also changes many logical symbols in my document.

I don't want to use the whole package, just some special symbols.

If it is any help, these are the packages I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

I apologize for the lack of code and form here, this is my first time using this stack exchange.

Comment: you can use ctrl-k to mark a code block or (as I just did) three `\`\`\``  before and after it (on their own lines)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)

Comment: @MS-SPO This question is not about a character from a particular font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alas, the precise thing you’re looking for isn’t exactly possible. The TeX engine was designed at a time of rather limited computing resources and namespacing was not on the menu at that time.

Instead, what you’ll need to do is look at the `oz` source code to see how `\fcmp` was defined.

When you run LaTeX, you’ll see a line that indicates where the `oz.sty` file is being read in by LaTeX so you know where the file is and you can open that in your favorite text editor (most likely what you’re using to edit your LaTeX files, natch). Doing a search through `oz.sty`¹ will reveal the following definition:

```
\def \fcmp  {\mathbin{\raise 0.6ex\hbox{\oalign{\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle
     \mathrm{o}$\hfil\cr\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{9}$\hfil}}}}
```

which shows how the `\fcmp` command is defined.

Now, there’s a bit of luck in that this doesn’t use any internal LaTeX commands, so you could just paste this right into your preamble in place of `\usepackage{oz}`, but there’s a caveat here: The way the command is defined apparently makes some assumptions necessary for the `objectz` package of which `oz` is part² where a space after `\fcmp` is *not* optional thanks to the use of the plain TeX `\def` command and the space(s) after `\fcmp` in the definition. Better to write:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\fcmp{}{\mathbin{\raise 0.6ex\hbox{\oalign{\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle
     \mathrm{o}$\hfil\cr\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{9}$\hfil}}}}
```

which will define `\fcmp` in a more LaTeX-native fashion.

---

1. Some, but not all, LaTeX packages will provide documentation of the source code which will might give an explanation of the choices made in implementing the package. ObjectZ, while it distributes a `.dtx` file which generates documentation, has no internal documentation of the choices made.
2. Or, it might just be an error on the package writer’s part.

Comment: There are no space _tokens_ after `\fcmp` in `\def \fcmp  {`

Answer (score 9):

I suggest *not* using the `\fcmp` from `oz.sty` (a set of kludges), but the semicolon from `bbold` or `\fatsemi` from `stmaryrd`.

Here's a comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand\fcmp{}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \raise 0.6ex\hbox{%
      \oalign{%
        \hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{o}$\hfil\cr
        \hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{9}$\hfil
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\altfcmp}{}{\mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n};}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\altfcmpbis}{}{\mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{stmry}{m}{n}\symbol{"23}}}}

\begin{document}

$a\fcmp b$

$a\altfcmp b$

$a\altfcmpbis b$

\end{document}
```

You decide whether you want the symbol to be `\mathbin` or have a different status.

[image]

How did I get `\fatsemi`? First I looked the manual for `stmaryrd` and saw that the glyph is called `\fatsemi`. Next the package code where there is

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}

\stmry@if\DeclareMathSymbol\fatsemi\mathbin{stmry}{"23}\fi
```

Thus I had all the ingredients to define the command without wasting a math symbol font for just one symbol.

Take your pick and use `\fcmp` (or whatever name you prefer) instead of the names I used just in order to do the comparison.